# Apache Rewrite Rule not Matching Colon (:)

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2

I'm having trouble writing a rule that will rewrite an address like **http://localhost/hello:world** to **http://localhost/hello/world.html**

My RewriteRule in httpd.conf is as follows:

```
<Directory "D:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^hello:world$ /hello/world.html [L,QSA] #Doesn't work
     RewriteRule ^hello_world$ /hello/world.html [L,QSA] #Works great!
 </Directory>
```

When I try **http://localhost/hello:world**, I receive a 403 Forbidden page.

Of particular note, the rule

```
RewriteRule ^hello_world$ /hello/world.html [L,QSA]
```

works just fine with **http://localhost/hello_world**.

I am using Apache2.2 under Windows Server 2008.

How would I rewrite the rule to match the colon?

Comment: Try putting a backslash in front of the colon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: What happens if you set it to rewrite $(.*)^ to, say, index.php?q=$1 and have index.php <?php echo $_GET['q']; ?> ? (Your rule as it is seems to work for me on Ubuntu Maverick, albeit in a .htaccess file)

Comment: @PeterJCLaw That RewriteRule also results in a 403 forbidden error if I pass any parameters with a colon.

Comment: That's odd. I'm wondering if you've got something in your apache config that's specifically blocking urls containing colon generally. Is anything useful appearing in the access.log or error.log files?

Comment: Hrm, after some googling it looks like this is a more general issue; colon is a reserved character (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/apache2/5tG-7WFR8_k) which even wikipedia fell foul of.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt.. Always escape

```
RewriteRule ^hello\:world$ /hello/world.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I've tried escaping the colon, but still got the 403 Forbidden error

Comment: I would expect that Apache expects it to be properly escaped as `%3A`.